# No file opening with a random music file player

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio-player

I am finding difficulty in coding a Python music player than plays a random artist. I have the mp3 files in a directory, but choosing them randomly is proving to be difficult. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```py
from tkinter import *

import os

import random

master = Tk()
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)

def quit_loop():
    print ("Selection:"),var.get()

    global selection
    selection = var.get()
    master.quit()

Label(master, text = "What is your mood?").grid(row=0, sticky=W)

Radiobutton(master, text = "Sad", variable=var, value = 1).grid(row=1,sticky=W)

Radiobutton(master, text = "Happy", variable=var, value = 2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)

Radiobutton(master, text = "Sleepy or Bored", variable=var, value = 3).grid(row=3, sticky=W)

Radiobutton(master, text = "Scared", variable=var, value = 4).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

Radiobutton(master, text = "Pumped or Angry", variable=var, value = 5).grid(row=5, sticky=W)

Button(master, text = "Show me the music!", command=quit_loop).grid(row=7, sticky=W)


master.mainloop()

if selection == 1:
    print ("My Value is equal to one.")

elif selection == 2:
    print ("My value is equal to two.")

elif selection == 3:
    print ("My value is equal to three.")

elif selection == 4:
    print ("My value is equal to four.")

elif selection == 5:
    random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\Dony Proj\Mood DJ\Do you like any of these\Beastie Boys"))
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to clarify it. What is your _specific_ question? "Proving to be difficult" isn't a question, or a clear problem statement. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're calling `random.choice` but are not assigning the return value to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already have it; I set the directory to one in my machine with some example music files and simply stored the random choice of file to a variable and added a print statement to see what it was:

```py
elif selection == 5:
    song_choice = random.choice(os.listdir(r"E:\music"))
    print(song_choice)
```

It then prints the name of a random song from my music directory!

Comment: I want it to open the file. I am unsure if this is possible, however.

Comment: If you were looking to _play_ the music file you could use a module such as [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org) or [sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io) to playback a given sound file. However (if you haven't yet) I recommend you get used to [reading and writing from basic text files](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp) as this should really help your understanding of interacting with files with python.